# How to add SSL for localhost in RAILS

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails

I want to test my application which needs to work both with and without SSL. If it is possible to set up SSL for a local application (http://localhost:3000), please let me know some suggestions, my OS is Ubuntu 10.4.

Comment: From the view of the application there is normally no difference if it gets served by http or https. So for simple testing I see no sense in your question...?